# Populating list view with SQL database rows

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a SQLite DB and want to display 
all it's rows within a customised list view.

What is best way  to populate the list view with data from the database ? Ie I have a image and two strings from each DB row I want to populate the list view components  with.

Thanks

Comment: you can get the data as list<yourClassData> and deal with it like any custom listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayAdapter, CursorAdapter, SimpleAdapter
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html